# Timer in Java Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, timer

I have a thread which is in charge of doing some processes. I want make it so that these processing would be done every 3 seconds. I've used the code below but when the thread starts, nothing happens.
I assumed that when I define a task for my timer it automatically execute the `ScheduledTask` within time interval but it doesn't do anything at all. 
What am I missing?

```
class temperatureUp extends Thread 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    TimerTask increaseTemperature = new TimerTask(){

        public void run() {
        try {
            //do the processing 
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    };

    Timer increaserTimer = new Timer("MyTimer");
    increaserTimer.schedule(increaseTemperature, 3000);

    }
};
```

Comment: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-schedule/index.html

Comment: Are you sure you are creating a `temperatureUp` thread and calling `start()` on it? This code works fine for me.

Comment: Why would you use both a thread and a timer? The timer runs on it's own thread

Comment: I think you should rethink the structure of your program. You have to consider a global timer (not for each thread). What if the processes take longer than 3 seconds? how will you end them gracefully? You need to give more information and more code please :)

Comment: @AljoshaBre I still don't know what's wrong with this code.

Comment: @JonLin I do start the tread.

Comment: @EsbenSkovPedersen I have a shared object and three different threads using that object. but I want the threads do do their processes in a specific time interval just so the user would be able to see the result of their actions in UI. When I used `Thread.Sleep()` instead of Timer, the UI was freezing on me.

Comment: Elham => your pasted code is horribly broken since you have a call(increaseTimer.schdule) inside a class definition.

Comment: Elham => using a timer because of the ui is an entirely wrong approach. I think you should make a new question where you ask how to update the ui during a long running operation.

Comment: @Elham : I didn't notice it before but you're spawning a new thread from within another thread? This is a very wrong approach. Consider changing your structure so that threads are spawned and schedule from a global level.

Comment: So I can't put schedule in my thread at all?!

Answer (score 27):

A few errors in your code snippet:

- You extend the `Thread` class, which is not really good practice
- You have a `Timer` within a `Thread`? That doesnt make sense as the a `Timer` runs on its own `Thread`.

You should rather (when/where necessary), implement a `Runnable` see [here](http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=4202) for a short example, however I cannot see the need for both a `Thread` and `Timer` in the snippet you gave.

Please see the below example of a working `Timer` which will simply increment the counter by one each time it is called (every 3seconds):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test {

    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                System.out.println("TimerTask executing counter is: " + counter);
                counter++;//increments the counter
            }
        };

        Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");//create a new Timer

        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 30, 3000);//this line starts the timer at the same time its executed
    }
}
```

**Addendum:**

I did a short example of incorporating a `Thread` into the mix. So now the `TimerTask` will merely increment `counter` by 1 every 3 seconds, and the `Thread` will display `counter`s value sleeping for 1 seconds every time it checks counter (it will terminate itself and the timer after `counter==3`):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class Test {

    static int counter = 0;
    static Timer timer;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //create timer task to increment counter
        TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                // System.out.println("TimerTask executing counter is: " + counter);
                counter++;
            }
        };

        //create thread to print counter value
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        System.out.println("Thread reading counter is: " + counter);
                        if (counter == 3) {
                            System.out.println("Counter has reached 3 now will terminate");
                            timer.cancel();//end the timer
                            break;//end this loop
                        }
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        timer = new Timer("MyTimer");//create a new timer
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 30, 3000);//start timer in 30ms to increment  counter

        t.start();//start thread to display counter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ThreadTimer extends TimerTask{
    static int counter = 0;

    public static void main(String [] args) {
        Timer timer = new Timer("MyTimer");
        timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new ThreadTimer(), 30, 3000);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("TimerTask executing counter is: " + counter);
        counter++;
   }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to do something every three seconds you should use scheduleAtFixedRate (see [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29)).

However your code really does nothing because you create a thread in which you start a timer just before the thread's run stops (there is nothing more to do). When the timer (which is a single shoot one) triggers, there is no thread to interrupt (run finished before).

```
class temperatureUp extends Thread 
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
    TimerTask increaseTemperature = new TimerTask(){

        public void run() {
        try {
            //do the processing 
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
        }
    };

    Timer increaserTimer = new Timer("MyTimer");
    //start a 3 seconds timer 10ms later
    increaserTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(increaseTemperature, 3000, 10);

    while(true) {
         //give it some time to see timer triggering
         doSomethingMeaningful();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the method you've used has the signature `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay)` . So in effect you're just delaying the start time of the ONLY execution.

To schedule it to run every 3 seconds you need to go with this method `schedule(TimerTask task, long delay, long period)` where the **third** param is used to give the period interval.

You can refer the Timer class definition here to be of further help

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html

Comment: with the line `increaserTimer.schedule(increaseTemperature, 2000, 2000);` still nothing happens!

Comment: @Elham -  I didn't notice it before but you're spawning a new thread from within another thread? This is a very wrong approach. Consider changing your structure so that threads are spawned and schedule from a global level. Here's a link with an example project that will help you change your structure: http://www.roseindia.net/java/example/java/util/CertainAndRepeatTime.shtml

Comment: in other words, I can't using Timer to schedule the series of actions which are done by a thread. right?

Comment: @Elham : TimerTask in itself can be called a Thread. You just define your thread functionality in run() function and you're good to go. Just there is no need to extend the Thread class and complicate your code. You must have a parent class, rite? Spawn a TimerTask from that parent class with a scheduled delay and an interval. Be sure to add some exit condition, otherwise this task will keep on running till the WebApp is up.

Comment: This is a class work. I need to use the thread class for this program.

Comment: Please add the tag homework to give us some indication. Now, ok I get the context. But do you need to use TimerTask also? There are implementations available without TimerTask but with Thread

Answer (score 1):

## `Timer` & `TimerTask` are legacy

The [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Timer.html) & `TimerTask` classes are now [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system). To run code at a certain time, or to run code repeatedly, use a [scheduled executor service](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html).

To quote the `Timer` class Javadoc:

> Java 5.0 introduced the java.util.concurrent package and one of the concurrency utilities therein is the ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor which is a thread pool for repeatedly executing tasks at a given rate or delay. It is effectively a more versatile replacement for the Timer/TimerTask combination, as it allows multiple service threads, accepts various time units, and doesn't require subclassing TimerTask (just implement Runnable). Configuring ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor with one thread makes it equivalent to Timer.

## Executor framework

In modern Java, we use the [Executors framework](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html) rather than directly addressing the [`Thread`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.html) class.

Define your task as a [`Runnable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Runnable.html) or [`Callable`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Callable.html). You can use compact lambda syntax seen below. Or you can use conventional syntax to define a class implementing the `Runnable` (or `Callable`) interface.

Ask a `ScheduledExecutorService` object to execute your `Runnable` object’s code every so often.

```java
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ;

Runnable task = () -> { 
    System.out.println( "Doing my thing at: " + Instant.now() );
};

long initialDelay = 0L ; 
long period = 3L ;
TimeUnit timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS ;
scheduledExecutorService.submit( task , initialDelay, period , timeUnit ) ;

…
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown() ;  // Stops any more tasks from being scheduled.
scheduledExecutorService.awaitTermination() ;  // Waits until all currently running tasks are done/failed/canceled.
```

Notice that we are not directly managing any `Thread` objects in the code above. Managing threads is the job of the executor service.

Tips:

- Always shutdown your executor service gracefully when no longer needed, or when your app exits. Otherwise the backing thread pool may continue indefinitely like a zombie ‍♂️.
- Consider wrapping your task's working code in a try-catch. Any uncaught exception or error reaching the scheduled executor service results in silently halting the further scheduling of any more runs.