# how to paint jrame components before another process starts

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jframe

```
private void addSomeComponentsToFrame(){
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
.....
frame.setVisible(true);

frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();

runOtherTask();
}
```

I want to see frame object and its components before runOtherTask method starts but when i try to run addSomeComponentsToFrame method, frame appears(as black rectangle) but freezes and after runOtherTask method completes it shows frame's components on screen.

Comment: You may use `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to prevent using more than one thread, that would ensure that `runOtherTask()` is executed after painting is complete. However if `runOtherTask()` is a long running task it is best to be executed in a dedicated thread and keep the EDT responsive.

Comment: @ExtremeCoders, I don't see how using `SwingUtilities` would help here..all it's going to do is place the `runOtherTask` event at the end of the event queue, which is where it'll be regardless in this scenario.

Comment: @mre I think he means creating only the Frame on EDT and calling the method outside of EDT thus it will block the intial thread and not GUI EDT

Comment: i found JComponent.paintImmediately method but i dont understand it.

Comment: JComponent.paintImmediately wont work for JFrame

Comment: I had a similar problem.  Removing double buffering solved my problem.  Every swing component has a setDoubleBuffered() option.  Disabling it fixed my problem.

Answer (score 3):

> when i try to run addSomeComponentsToFrame method, frame appears(as
>   black rectangle) but freezes and after runOtherTask method completes
>   it shows frame's components on screen.

Sounds like you are blocking the [`Event Dispatch Thread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html) with a long running task.

You might want to offload that task from your EDT to a separate *thread*:

If you manipulate Swing components in `runOtherTask` better to use :

- [Swing Worker](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12641887/swingworker-in-java/12642215#12642215) example)
- [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14074329/using-sleep-for-a-single-thread/14074427#14074427) example)

Otherwise you can use (Note the below does not run in the GUIs `Event Dispatch Thread` thus manipulating Swing components in them is not allowed):

- [Thread](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html)
- [Timer/TimerTask](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) (See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707066/timer-in-java-thread/11707987#11707987) example)

Just as a side note no need for:

```
frame.getContentPane().validate();
frame.getContentPane().repaint();
```

simply:

```
frame.validate();
frame.repaint();
```

Also if your java version allows use `revalidate()` instead of `validate()`. But these are only necessary if adding/removing a component from a visible container.